# #Ubuntu Install .net core 5 framework

Tags: .net-5, .net-6.0

I installed .net6 but i need to have installed .net5

So, I removed .net6 and I installed .net5.

Now, when I run 'dotnet build' command I have the error:

> A fatal error occurred. The folder [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/host/fxr] does not exist

Do you have some idea to help me, please.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 5 has reached its End of Life. If you are using it, you are on your own; don't expect any fixes for security issues that discovered every few weeks.

Anyway, sounds like you are using Ubuntu 22.04.

If so, you are out of luck. There's no simple way to install or run .NET 5 there. .NET 5 needs OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1. Ubuntu 22.04 only has OpenSSL 3.0. Even if you install and manage to run .NET 5, it wont work and you will get OpenSSL errors.

Your best course of action is to install an older version of Ubuntu, such as 20.04.

Your specific error in this case is quite unrelated to above, though. Your error is because you seem to have installed some packages from Ubuntu's package repository and some packages from Microsoft's package repository. See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699#issuecomment-1222470580 for details. In particular you want to follow the steps in "Mixed state scenario 2: Use PMC packages after installing native Jammy packages". But that's not needed on Ubuntu 20.04 or similar OS that you need to make .NET 5 work at all.